# is it possible to get inline css in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a chrome extension and I wanted to know if there is a way to get inline css in chrome extension development. I also wanted updated inline css if someone updated it ? Please help me if anyone have an answer. I have tried chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow and able to get current and updated css files but not inline css.

Comment: Do you want to change inline css in the inspected window?

Comment: No, I want to get inline css in my chrome extension.

Comment: Did you make this plugin? I was just looking for something like this today and came across your post.

Comment: I made one attemp in this plugin, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-saver/gbbffkedhojnicnhiijkoahiljphngoe?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon.